# How to access multiple Skype accounts in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: skype

Around 2 days ago, I was able to access multiple Skype accounts. But now I do not know what has happened and I am unable to access multiple Skype accounts in the way I did before.

Is there any way to fix the issue and access multiple Skype accounts?

Comment: A couple of days ago was the general uplift from v2 skype to v4 - which one have you now got installed?

Comment: Skype 4.0.0.8-0oneirc1

Answer (score 22):

Skype (4.1, at least) includes the `--secondary` command line option to open a second instance. One could create a launcher and add this to the command.

See `skype --help` for more options.

Comment: This is really nice trick even works in **Ubuntu 14.04** too with **Skype `4.3.0.37`** ,  but when we close the terminal skype closed too

Comment: @diEcho Try this: skype --secondary &

Comment: Thanks. This `&` close the command line itself with `pid` in terminal but closing the terminal will close the Skype.I think this is the final thing :)

Answer (score 5):

1. `cp -a ~.Skype/ ~.Skype2/`
2. Create `~/Skype2` and put a new document in it named `skype2`.
3. Edit the file `skype2` and add `skype --dbpath=~./.Skype2`.
4. Change permissions on `skype2` to allow execution.
5. Launch `skype2` and enjoy.

Comment: what is the command line for step `3` and location would be `~/.` rather than `~.`

Answer (score 2):

You can for sure use 2 accounts without any configurations. when you will start skype, it will be run as normal user you are. If you wish to run another just do

```
sudo /usr/bin/skype
```

It will start another skype, for root user. So this is something handy. If you want 3 or more, then above method may be the only option. or you can just create some more users, and switch to them at command line using

```
su username
```

Enter your other users name you created, enter password and keep running `/usr/bin/skype` command.

Comment: I think this answer is rather dangerous as it's not recommended to run programs as root unless they have a good reason for it. (Remember with root you have access to more delicate system settings!).
Better clone program's settings and create an executable with a parameter to launch Skype with the cloned profile you can then alter. Pernecker's answer describes the necessary steps.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal, and run

```
skype --secondary
```

Answer (score 0):

Run skype `--help` command in command prompt
so response is

```
vipinjain@vipinjain:~$ skype --help 
Skype 4.3.0.37

    Usage: skype [options]
    Options:
      --dbpath=<path>       Specify an alternative path to store Skype data files.
                            Default: ~/.Skype
      --resources=<path>    Specify a path where Skype can find its resource files.
                            Default: /usr/share/skype
      --secondary           Start a secondary instance of Skype.
      --disable-api         Disable Skype Public API.
      --callto <nick>
      skype:<nick>?<action>
                            These commands allow Skype links handling.
      --pipelogin           Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
      --version             Display version information and exit.
```

There is `--secondary` command for open the secondary skype, if you want to open another then open `command prompt` and type `--secondary` command and again and again whenever you run this command its open new instance of skype.
Try This for open multiple instance of skype